# Transform Julien date and timestamp in correct durations

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB with this data (extract - there are more columns - totally)
The first is the name, the second the department.
Then there is at CJDate the JDE Julian date - Format.
And cStart and cEnds inludes the timestamp.

[image]

I would like to get the Date in the Format "DD.MM.YYYY" and the duration between cStart and cEnd in "D.HH:MM:SS". 
But there are some exotics. If there are values in cEnd between 0 and 62000, the cJDate should be -1. 
Is it possible to get the correct duration, if cEnd has the value 240000?Or sould it be transformed in 23:59:59 or in cJDate -1 and 00:00:00?

I use already this, to get the correct date:

```
DATE '1900-01-01' + FLOOR(ZZ."cJDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL'1' YEAR+
(MOD(ZZ."cJDate", 1000) -1) * INTERVAL'1' DAY AS "Date",
```

Does someone have any idea?

Best regards

Comment: This is not a "Julian" date (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar).  You'll need to explain the format of the values that you have.

Comment: `(I think?)` should be a giant red warning siren to you.  If you're not really ***certain*** about the ***exact*** format of a column, you can not reliably interpret it.  You need to find out the ***definitive*** way in which that column is intended to be interpreted, only then can you consider how to implement that in SQL.

Comment: 119001 is 01.01.2019. 118001 is the 01.01.2018

Comment: Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Until now I've been using this:

```
select to_date(to_char(cjDate), 'YYYDDD')
from dual;
```

Is not julian date it's more like [JDE Julian date](http://peoplesoft.macek.cc/dateconverter.php?)

Example output:

> 118316 → 12/11/18